What is the meaning of "against" in "against such things there is no law" Galatians 5:23?
Galatians 5:22-23 ESV

"But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, patience, kindness, goodness, faithfulness, 23 gentleness, self-control; against such things there is no law." [My emphasis]

Here kata is translated "against".
From Matthew 10:35

"For I have come to set a man against his father..". [kata/against]

Here a man is in opposition or fighting against "enemies" [Ma 10:36]
Mark 1:27

"What is this? A new teaching with authority." [kata/with]

"Teaching" here is supported by/with "authority". [ A ladder "against" a wall is not fighting the wall but supported by it]
In Galatians 5:23 is the sense of "against" either:

There is no law that fights against such things [the fruit of the Spirit].

There is no law which supports/leans against/helps facilitate the Spirit producing  fruit?



Why not "against" in the same sense as "law against murder" -- a law forbidding such things?

The operative word, a preposition, here is κατὰ (kata) which has two distinct meanings depending on the grammatical case of the following word (see BDAG or any other good lexicon):

κατὰ with GENITIVE means "against", eg, Gal 5:23, Matt 10:35.
κατὰ with ACCUSATIVE means "with", eg, Mark 1:27.

Now, this is the situation stated simplistically; good lexicons will give a much more complete and nuanced set of definitions.
In Gal 5:23, Paul says that there is no law "against" those possessing the nine fruits of the Spirit, love, joy, peace, etc.  What does Paul mean?  he states this in several other places such as:

Gal 5:17, 18 - For the flesh desires against [kata] the Spirit, and the Spirit against [kata] the flesh. For these are opposed to one another in order that you should not do those things you might wish. But if you are led by the Spirit, you are not under the law. [That is, under the condemnation of the law.]
Rom 8:33 - Who will bring an accusation against [kata] the elect of God?  God is the One who justifies.
Col 2:14 - having canceled the charge of our legal indebtedness [sinfulness, see V13], which stood against [kata] us and condemned us; he has taken it away, nailing it to the cross.

Thus, in Gal 5:23, Paul is teaching an important lesson that those with the fruit of the Spirit, those motivated by the Spirit (as opposed to the law of sin and death") have no sin recorded against them and thus, there is no law against them.

Thanks. You say "important" what lesson/truth? Also death" but " by itself. You say "no sin recorded against them" them here = people [I think] but "such things" are not people. "Such things"  are fruits of the Spirit, not people [I think].

@C.Stroud - "things" is not in the Greek which simply says, "against such there is no law".  Law cannot apply to things, only people.  The implied word is (with Dottard's paraphrase), "against such people (motivated by the spirit) there is no law."

πραΰτης, ἐγκράτεια· κατὰ τῶν τοιούτων οὐκ ἔστιν νόμος.
κατὰ+genitive. This is a preposition, but I'd invite readers to think of it as a primitive one that's still a bit like a particle. Where English prepositions like 'against' are more physical and introduce strong converses (for! or against!) , κατὰ derives its metaphysical senses from its grammatical ones: this is a soft linguistic clue to the listener that two ideas are about to be contrasted.
English struggles with this softness, but we can at least start with an NT lexicon for this job, since little words like κατὰ are used so constantly that they are volatile over time and space.

from Arndt&Gingrich (1971):
2 - figuratively
2a - in verbs of swearing to denote what one swears by
2bi - in a hostile sense: against
2bii - after words and expressions that designate hostile speech, esp.
an accusation against someone
2c - after expressions which designate such a position or state of
mind in a different way

I think 2c is closest (but remember they are not really separate). The lexicon gives an example from the (non-canonical) Gospel of Peter 5:17
ετελειωσαν κατα της κεφαλης αυτων τα αμαρτηματα
they completed the full measure of sins against their own head

The Matthew example in the OP would be a usage 2bi, so if we trust the lexicon we don't need to analyse that.
And the OP's closing question never arises, because a Greek-literate writer isn't distinguishing between against as in "fights against" and against as in "leans against".
The thing with Paul's idiom νόμος + κατὰ + genitive noun is that if you made a law mandating everyone to eat their fries with ketchup, it could be called the νόμος κατὰ τομάτασαπρόυ.
And to say the legal code "of" King Ketchup, the tyrant Tomatasapros, they would change Τομάτασαπρόν to the accusative case, without noticing any difference in κατὰ. Ancient Greek achieves precision of meaning through the morphology of its predicates not just from the choice of preposition. English does not have this option.
So because of how English arranges our idioms around our strong converses: when κατὰ is an "against" it's an "against" in the sense that it could be a "for". But obviously from the context we should use an against in Galatians 5:23. (And the word does carry a faint negative register. And the Greek, Roman and Jewish legal systems were on the principle of prohibition, so when the listener hears "law" and "about" we can assume they naturally expect a law against it, which I would think of as proto-idiom)
yay versus boo
When English wants a neutral idiom we say "about" but in Greek that's to replace a firm, laser-line syntatic purposivity, with a vague orbit. It's not against rather than about because of 'positive vs. negative' but because of 'specific vs. vague'.
And this is also needed for the other example the OP has in Mark 1:27. Greek isn't saying the teaching is supported by the authority: it's that there is drawn a tight purposive link. Derived from, according to.
The ladder/wall idea is only similar in English - that would be a physical sense of κατὰ and would then be marking the logical relationship, the wall-ladder contrast, not the ladder's moral attitude of "yay! wall!"

In Galatians 5:23, the phrase "against such things there is no law" (πραΰτης ἐγκράτεια· κατὰ τῶν τοιούτων οὐκ ἔστιν νόμος) speaks to the nature of the virtues listed, such as gentleness and self-control. Here, "against" (κατὰ) implies an opposition or resistance, commonly used in Greek to convey being "against" something in terms of legality or moral conflict. Paul is emphasizing that these virtues are aligned with the highest ethical and spiritual standards, so much so that no law stands in opposition to them.
In considering the Greek terms "τοιούτην" (such things) and "νόμος" (law), we can look at 1 Esdras 8:86-87 and Hosea 8:1–3, where we see similar terms associated with the law in relation to moral behavior and covenant faithfulness. In 1 Esdras 8:87, the phrase indicates that God's law forms a "root" or foundation for righteousness, contrasting with the impurity of the surrounding nations, thus reinforcing that following God's law brings a person into alignment with the "good" (ἀγαθά) rather than opposition. Hosea 8:1-3, by contrast, describes how Israel "transgressed" the covenant and opposed (κατὰ) the law of God, choosing evil rather than the goodness that aligns with divine principles.
In Galatians, "against" in "against such things there is no law" implies that these virtues are intrinsically good and harmonious with God's intent. They represent the highest good (ἀγαθά) for humanity, transcending any legal restrictions or requirements. Therefore, possessing these virtues aligns a person with the spirit of the law and fulfills its ultimate purpose, standing beyond any opposition or judgment.
In Galatians 3:21, Paul asks rhetorically, "Is the law then against the promises of God?" (ὁ οὖν νόμος κατὰ τῶν ἐπαγγελιῶν τοῦ θεοῦ; μὴ γένοιτο). His answer is emphatic: "Certainly not!" This clarifies that the law is not opposed to God’s promises; rather, it was given to guide and prepare people until the coming of Christ, through whom the promise is fully realized. In Galatians 5:23, the phrase "against such things there is no law" reflects this harmony between the law and the virtues listed, suggesting that these virtues—such as gentleness and self-control—not only align with the law but fulfill its highest purpose.
Just as the law is not contrary to God’s promises in Galatians 3:21, the fruits of the Spirit in Galatians 5:23 encounter no legal opposition or restriction. In both verses, the term "against" (κατὰ) highlights the concept of something that opposes or conflicts with a foundational principle. In Galatians 5:23, "against such things" reinforces the idea that these virtues are inherently good and aligned with the spirit of the law, so there is no conflict or opposition possible. They represent the fulfillment of the ultimate good (ἀγαθά), going beyond mere external conformity to the law and embodying the complete ethical and spiritual purpose of God’s divine law.
In this way, both Galatians 3:21 and 5:23 convey that the divine law ultimately aims at the highest good. In the context of Galatians 5:23, Paul shows that cultivating these virtues transcends any need for legal restriction, as they embody the ethical ideal of both the law and God’s promises.
